# Add a suffix based on a pattern in rows

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that looks like this:

> ```
>       names         value1          Value2       
>      S1_xxx-1        9.65            1.24
>      S1_xxx-1        1.15            3.64
>      S1_xxx-1        3.05            1.65
>      S2_xxx-1        7.12            6.109
>      S2_xxx-1        8.9             6.03
>      S2_xxx-1        4.23            2.10
>      .......        ......          ......
> ```

with S* from S1 to S16 and _xxx- are some letters.
Is there a way to obtain the following output on the first column?

> ```
>       names           value1          Value2       
>      S1_xxx-1-0        9.65            1.24
>      S1_xxx-1-0        1.15            3.64
>      S1_xxx-1-0        3.05            1.65
>      S2_xxx-1-1        7.12            6.109
>      S2_xxx-1-1        8.9             6.03
>      S2_xxx-1-1        4.23            2.10
>      .......        ......          ......
> ```

i.e. when there is S1* I would like to add -0 as a suffix to all the rows having S1*.
Equally, when there is S2* I would like to add -1 as a suffix to all the rows having S2* and so on until S16* that will have -15 as a suffix.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We extract the digits with `parse_number`, subtract 1, and `paste` with the 'names'

```
df1$names <- with(df1, paste0(names, '-', readr::parse_number(names) -1))

df1$names
#[1] "S1_xxx-1-0" "S1_xxx-1-0" "S1_xxx-1-0" "S2_xxx-1-1" "S2_xxx-1-1" "S2_xxx-1-1"
```

---

Or similar option in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(names = str_c(names, readr::parse_number(names), sep = '-'))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(names = c("S1_xxx-1", "S1_xxx-1", "S1_xxx-1", 
"S2_xxx-1", "S2_xxx-1", "S2_xxx-1"), value1 = c(9.65, 1.15, 3.05, 
7.12, 8.9, 4.23), Value2 = c(1.24, 3.64, 1.65, 6.109, 6.03, 2.1
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is perfect!